# Can Laravel Blade be used in a sandbox environment?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

Can Laravel Blade be used in a sandbox environment, similar to Twig's sandbox extension?

I have the need to allow users to use a template system but obviously do not want them executing arbitrary PHP code on the server.

I would like to use Blade since it's already part of Laravel but suspect this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, by default.

You could probably implement this yourself however, by extend blade to add custom functionality. See the [Blade Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#extending-blade).